# Is this setup.txt file important?

Tags: windows, setup

I have this file txt file in local disk c:/

I do not know what it is but it makes my drive c: look ugly. Can I move this somewhere elseor delete it? Is it important?
 [image]

Comment: Just rename it or move it for a while. If nothing complains, it's probably safe to delete it.

Comment: This Windows folder makes your drive c: ugly ;)

Comment: @mpy Yeah, rename it and see if anything complains. ;)

Comment: @techie007 I am a newb but not falling for that one.

Comment: It is 100% safe to remove, but you don't need to. I  suggest you leave it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely delete the file, as it is the output from your network card installer when it was installed. Basically it is telling you the version of the driver and the company and that it successfully installed.

Comment: Well Done Ian for identifying the actual content and reason for the file.

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to delete it safely, it's just a log file of some type.